# npm is installed using nvm but IntelliJ does not know about it

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, nvm

I installed NPM using NVM.

When I use npm in Intellij terminal, it says I don't have NPM installed. But if I use Ubuntu terminal, it is working.

Here are what I tried:

I have already tried to set my node interpreter (in "Language and Framework" > "Node and NPM", set to `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.8.0/bin/node`).

I have also already enabled the Node.js Core library. There it shows the npm package is included.

But the IntelliJ terminal still complains I haven't installed npm. Why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is because idea terminal launches a login shell by default, so the .bashrc file is not read.

To solve the problem:

Open "Settings" in IntelliJ. Then, expand "Tools" in the left panel, then click 'Terminal'.

Add -i to the Shell Path. (eg. /bin/bash -i)

Comment: Does this work with newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: After adding this, I had to close and reopen the IntelliJ for this to work. I am using the latest IntelliJ.

Comment: This also solved it for me using zsh: /bin/zsh -i

Answer (score 22):

```
ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

The command will create a symlink from the current node version you have installed. If there is already a /usr/local/bin/node file, delete that since it might be a broken link.

Also change in Edit Configuration from whatever project version you have to "node" (which will be the link created with the above command)
[image: Edit Configurations]

Comment: simple and works, thankyou brother. good job!

Comment: Thankyou I have been struggling with this issue for weeks

Comment: Running `which node` results `/usr/local/bin/node`. So that would build a symlink to itself, if I get it right. So the problem remains.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher uninstall node and install it back using FNM https://github.com/Schniz/fnm

Comment: I've been struggling with this for over an hour. You're a life saver!

Comment: Does not work if you then switch node versions.

Comment: @kamcknig then point it to current version used by fnm/nvm

Comment: @Tudor, I understand that would need to be done, thanks. just wanted people to know. I myself had misunderstood and thought this was meant to automatically handle the case if you switch node versions with nvm and didn't realize I'd still have to manually update a link. In this case it's simply  easier to add the .nvm/versions/<version> to the list in webstorm. Though I suppose that would clutter up the IDE with a lot of versions and someone might not like that.

Comment: Good explanation of the issue

Answer (score 9):

This fixed it for me:

> NVM patches environment variables on terminal startup only. If the IDE is launched from Terminal, it inherits Terminal environment (including modified PATH environment variable, added NVM_DIR env var, etc). In that case, there are normally no problems with using node/npm, because Idea sees the correct PATH value.
> For bash as shell, workaround could be the the following: edit your Idea launcher and set command to "/bin/bash -l -c "/path/to/idea.sh". This command will perform bash login (i.e. reading your .bashrc/.bash_profile files) and after that will run idea

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205964744/comments/205060164

Just edit your Intellij launcher / startup script and change that to `/bin/bash -i -c <path to idea.sh>`

Comment: How do we find the path to `ide.sh`?

Comment: Check the properties of your launcher shortcut. You'll find the launcher in `/usr/share/applications` (for global install) or `~/.local/share/applications` (for local install)

Comment: Worked on phpstorm 2020.1 and Kubuntu. Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 9):

Adding the nvm node interpreter worked for me:

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM -> Node interpreter

Chose `~/.nvm/current/bin/node`. If it doesn't show up in the interpreter selection, click `...` and add it as a new path.

Comment: Working on WebStorm 2021.1.3 - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am running on Ubuntu and had the same issue shown by not being able to run node from the IntelliJ Idea terminal or being able to run gradle tasks that start a nvm related process.

Some of the existing answers fixed it for me when using the terminal within Idea, but running the gradle tasks still did not work. Starting it with bash -l -c... as found elsewhere did not work either.

Initially solved it by creating a start script that does the same as what nvm does, and then did the bash -l -c... and that worked, but found (after that) that the -i as stated above works as well and is simpler... So my .desktop exec entry line is now:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -i -c /opt/intellij/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh "%f"
```

Just mentioning it here as the accepted solution does not work for starting nvm related gradle tasks from within Idea.

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution was to move the following lines from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` and reboot/relogin.

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 4):

does it help if you run IntelliJ as admin? On Windows this solves many of the issues I had with setting up Node, Bower and Git

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. I did gksudo -k -u root "/opt/idea-IU-162.2032.8/bin/idea.sh" %f to run IntellIjJ as root, and I tried node --version inside, and it still doesn't show anything. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using webstorm on mac and had to add path variable to `~/.zshenv` (which is the zsh version of ~/.bash_profile):

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in mac OS catalina, fixed it by updating Shell path to /bin/zsh in Preferences -> Tools -> Terminal -> Application Settings.

Answer (score 1):

As Elena Pogorelova pointed out on the [Jetbrains forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205964744/comments/360000170179) the reason why the IDE cannot find the Node script when using NVM is that:

> When being launched from desktop/System menu, IDE only sees environment variables configured in `~/.profile` (login shell), but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `~/.bashhrc`).

So, what I found the best solution is moving the NVM initialization instructions from the `~/.bashrc` file to the `~/.profile` and reboot after that. In my case was:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your environment(s) is(are) different from running intellij and which bash session you ran `nvm <command (install/use)>`.  It is usually a good idea to add that line nvm recommends to add into your `~/.bashrc` that will export the needed environment variables into each of your bash sessions.  If you can run `node --version` from bash and it prints v6.8.0, your environment is correct, you just need to run intellij from that context, personally I'm not a fan of IDEs so I wouldn't know exactly, but I imagine intellij has a way to be executed from the command line.

Comment: If you mean this line of code, export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" , it is already added and I did source ~/.bashrc but the one it outputs is v4.2.6 from /usr/bin/node --version, instead of the v6.8.0 one installed with nvm, that means it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @RaymondPang ok good, then you probably just need to run intellij from the command line, so that those environment variables are within intellij's environment.

Comment: @RaymondPang Christian is right, your issue is that NVM's env vars aren't being passed to intellij due to is not being a child process of bash.  See http://linuxcourse.rutgers.edu/rute/node12.html section 9.9 for details

Comment: @Christian Grabowski I typed /opt/idea-IU-162.2032.8/bin/idea.sh in Terminal to launch intelliJ,  Is this exactly what you mean by "running from the command line"? After that, I still cannot get the same environment variable and Node in intelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by pointing to `/usr/local/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this works for me...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the PATH was different and didn't contain the path to the `nvm` folder. I just had to run `nvm use` inside Intellij terminal:

`nvm use <any installed node version>`

After that, Intellij PATH was updated with nvm folder path and `node` and `npm` commands worked normally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After trying most of the solutions presented here, the solution from Igor Kalinovskiy eventually fixed it for me on Mac:

> Add export `NVM_SYMLINK_CURRENT=true` to your .bashrc before NVM-stuff. Then do `nvm use default` - symlink is created. Then add `$HOME/.nvm/current/bin` to your `PATH` in .profile

Original answer: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205964744/comments/360000199399

Instead of `nvm use default`, you might want to use another version in the IntelliJ shell, e.g., `nvm use stable` or `nvm use 16`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this in Windows.

When running commands similar to `npm install` or `nvm list` using PowerShell and GitBash and would get errors like

> bash: nvm: command not found in IntelliJ

After inspecting the path in IntelliJ terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

could see that the paths to nvm and nodejs weren't being listed. Yet the same command in a terminal outside IntelliJ would list them correctly.

To fix it, simply added these paths within IntelliJ by adding the following entries to the Path variables

- `NVM_HOME`: `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\nvm`
- `NODE_PATH`: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: press "CTRL + SHIFT + A" and search by "node", click 2 times in "npm"

Step 2: Select the version and click in install.

[image: CTRL + SHIFT + A and search by "Node", click 2 times in "npm"]

[image: select the version npm you want, and click in install, the IDE will install and recognize the version to use now.]